# Exercise in Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $D\subset H $ verifying the property :
$$\forall y \in H, \quad \exists M_{y} \in \mathbb{R}^{+} \text {such that }|\langle x, y\rangle| \leq M_{y}, \quad \forall x \in D$$ We consider $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$, the set $H_n=\{y \in H:|\langle x, y\rangle| \leq n, \forall x \in D\} .$ \

1. Show that $(H_n)^o  \neq \varnothing $ ?
2. show that $\forall y_0\in (H_n)^o, \exists r>0$  such that
   $$|\langle x, z\rangle| \leq \frac{1}{r} \left(n_0+M_{y_0}\right), \quad \forall z \in \bar{B}(0,1), \quad \forall x \in D$$
   My attempt:

For $1$  we have $H_{n}=\{y \in H:|\langle x, y\rangle| \leq n, \forall x \in D\}=\{y \in H:-n \leq <x, y> \leq n, \forall x \in D\} = \bigcap_{x\in D}f^{-1}([-n,n])f\in H^* . $

For $2$ we have $y_0\in (H_{n})^°$ so $\exists r>0$ such that $B(y_0,r)\subset H_n$ we know that
$B(y_0,r)= y_0+rB(0,1) \subset H_n $ now let $z\in B(0,1)$ 
I'm stuck here any help THANK YOU

Comment: Proper usage is $\langle x,y\rangle, $ not $<x,y>. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy ok thanks for editing

Comment: For 1. use $H_n=n\cdot H_1$ and the Baire categoricity theorem.

Comment: @Berci TY for the Hint i will try